# How do I remove specific characters/whitespace from a list in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I read a CSV file as a DataFrame using the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.read_csv('listing.csv')
```

I dropped all of the rows in the DataFrame that contained no description and reset the index:

```
no_description = df['Description'].isna()
descriptions = df[~no_description].reset_index()
```

One of the rows was offset by one space, so I had to shift it one space to the left by the following:

```
descriptions.iloc[538, -17:] = descriptions.iloc[538, -17:].shift(-1)
```

The problem is that a column that contains a description that looks like a list, but it's being read as a string. Here's an example of a DataFrame row:

| Index | Category | Title | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Treehouse | Red Kite Tree Tent | ['About this Space', 'On the Domaine de l 'Arbre', 'in Cabane\n\n'] |
| 2 | Treehouse | Nature Cabin | ['About this Space', 'Nature is everywhere\n\nA', 'treehouse to indulge, relax and go where no one will be'] |

I used `literal_eval` to convert the descriptions into a list.

```
df['Description'] = df['Description'].apply(literal_eval)
```

I had to do this to remove the first item 'About this Space' in the list for all the rows in the column. I used slicing to achieve this.

```
descriptions['Description'] = descriptions['Description'].str[1:]
```

Now, the problem is that this list contains some whitespace ('\n') in it and if I join this list into a string, this leads to lots of whitespace and line breaks in the data.

I've tried removing the whitespace using `.strip()`, `.replace()` and even some `lambda` functions, but nothing seems to be working for me. An example:

```
descriptions['Description'] = descriptions['Description'].str.replace('\n', '')
```

This results in `'nan'` being returned.

What would be the simplest way to deal with this?

Comment: Can you post the actual contents of the CSV and the actual commands to get to where you are?  It's kind of hard to tell exactly how escaped something is or what data type it may have from this.  (Also, applying ast.literal_eval to something not meant as python data? Maybe not a great idea.)

Comment: @DanielMcLaury I just updated the post, I included all the commands that I used to get where I am. I simplified the table a little in the post as the actual DataFrame is huge, but it's essentially the same with regards to the data it contains

Comment: Can you post at least the header and one row of the CSV file?

Comment: Sure, would a screenshot be enough? Or should I paste it all in?

Comment: paste the first few lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the replace working by using .apply:

```
df['Description'].apply(lambda x: list(map(lambda val: val.replace("\n", ""), x)))
```

I believe the reason you were getting 'nan' values was that it is still treating that initial call you're making as lists while using string functions.